# iOS text display two different fonts for Japanese unexpectedly

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, cjk

[image]

I'm not sure this is a bug in iOS Japanese font, but `UITextView` with same font in Japanese displayed different fonts. As you can see the picture above, front part of second line contains す and middle part also contains す but their fonts are different!! I set the font to `UIFont.systemFont:`. This is kinda critical to me because I calculated text height based on text and because Japanese text contains different fonts, its calculation became inaccurate.

Any idea why and how to solve this problem?

rawText:

チャネルは、世界で最もリーズナブルなウェブ接客ツールです。 毎月数万円以上もするサービスとは異なり、起業したばかりのスタートアップや小規模サイトにも気軽に導入できます。(一人当たり約6米ドル/月程度) また、オペレーターの数に対して課金されるため、従量課金のサービスとは異なりトラフィックの大きな大規模サイトでもスケーラビリティを気にすることなくお使いいただけます

Update:

I found that using only hiragana will use same font over textview. But when a text contains mix of hiragana and Chinese characters, it displayed somehow different fonts for same hiragana. I confirmed that it happened even on iMessage App.

Comment: Please give a reasonable statement for downvote . This is iOS related programming problem when I calculate text height.

Comment: please add the raw text that you are setting into it